# How to decipher Erlang runtime error message

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang

When I run an Erlang function using IntelliJ's "Run Configuration", I am getting the following error message. The error message contains lot of nested brackets. Please help me in understanding the message.

```
"C:\Program Files\Erlang OTP\bin\erl.exe" -pa F:/1TB/P/workspace-IntelliJ-Erlang2/netconfClient/out/production/netconfClient -pa F:/1TB/P/workspace-IntelliJ-Erlang2/netconfClient -eval netconfManager:open2(). -s init stop -noshell
init terminating in do_boot ({badarg,[{ets,select,[ct_attributes,[_]],[{_}]},{ct_config,get_key_from_name,1,[{_},{_}]},{ct_util,does_connection_exist,3,[{_},{_}]},{ct_gen_conn,do_start,4,[{_},{_}]},{ct_netconfc,open,4,[{_},{_}]},{erl_eval,do_apply,7,[{_},{_}]},{init,start_it,1,[{_},{_}]},{init,start_em,1,[{_},{_}]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...{"init terminating in do_boot",{badarg,[{ets,select,[ct_attributes,[{{ct_conf,'$1','_','_','_',undefined,'_'},[],['$1']}]],[{error_info,#{cause=>id,module=>erl_stdlib_errors}}]},{ct_config,get_key_from_name,1,[{file,"ct_config.erl"},{line,578}]},{ct_util,does_connection_exist,3,[{file,"ct_util.erl"},{line,577}]},{ct_gen_conn,do_start,4,[{file,"ct_gen_conn.erl"},{line,281}]},{ct_netconfc,open,4,[{file,"ct_netconfc.erl"},{line,424}]},{erl_eval,do_apply,7,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,744}]},{init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1234}]},{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1220}]}]}}
done
```

Right click on a function in a .erl file and click on "Run ."

Answer (score 2):

The error message consists of Error code and Stack trace.

1. Error code is `badarg`. Please refer to
   [Exit Reasons](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html) for the list of error code.
2. The stack trace contains one entry for each function call. Each call
   provides file name, function name, line number. For example,
   `{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1220}]}` indicates that
   init.erl is the file, start_em is the function and 1220 is line #.

After manual indentation, we could better visualize the stacktrace as follows.

```
{badarg,[
{ets,select,[ct_attributes,[_]],[{_}]},
{ct_config,get_key_from_name,1,[{_},{_}]},
{ct_util,does_connection_exist,3,[{_},{_}]},
{ct_gen_conn,do_start,4,[{_},{_}]},
{ct_netconfc,open,4,[{_},{_}]},
{erl_eval,do_apply,7,[{_},{_}]},
{init,start_it,1,[{_},{_}]},
{init,start_em,1,[{_},{_}]}
]}

{badarg,[
{ets,select,[ct_attributes,[{{ct_conf,'$1','_','_','_',undefined,'_'},[],['$1']}]],[{error_info,#{cause=>id,module=>erl_stdlib_errors}}]},
{ct_config,get_key_from_name,1,[{file,"ct_config.erl"},{line,578}]},
{ct_util,does_connection_exist,3,[{file,"ct_util.erl"},{line,577}]},
{ct_gen_conn,do_start,4,[{file,"ct_gen_conn.erl"},{line,281}]},
{ct_netconfc,open,4,[{file,"ct_netconfc.erl"},{line,424}]},
{erl_eval,do_apply,7,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,744}]},
{init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1234}]},
{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1220}]}
]}
```